# knife configure -i fails

Tags: chef-infra, knife

Running knife I keep on getting this error, google does not seem to help much

```
WARNING: No knife configuration file found
Where should I put the config file? [/home/ubuntu/.chef/knife.rb] 
ERROR: Ohai::Exceptions::DependencyNotFound: Can not find a plugin for dependency os
```

This is a on a Ubuntu 13.10 server. Anyone have any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to 11.12.4+

[The fix is in the Chef code in 11.12.4.rc1](https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/11.12.4.rc.1/lib/chef/knife/configure.rb), the same 1 line fix as mentioned in user34's answer. Upgrading to 11.12.4+, when released, should solve the problem.

Rich

Answer (score 7):

Looks like its a bug as noted by the Chef folks but the link he gave is broken/missing.

http://lists.opscode.com/sympa/arc/chef/2014-04/msg00174.html

Im seeing the same issue by the way. What version of chef are you using?

EDIT: Got the link to work. Their mailing list was adding some hidden chars on the end of the URL... This might help you out: https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-5211

Answer (score 7):

There is a patch out for this, the ticket number is 5211 on their jira patch tracker. Update the configure.rb file. You can find it by running (find / -name "configure.rb") that will return the location just do a vi on that and put in that line of code, and you should be all set. 
https://github.com/opscode/chef/pull/1374/files

Comment: Superb! very simple instead of upgrading server.. Thanks